# xrandr only lists default output

Tags: 20.04, nvidia

All of a sudden xrandr only lists default output and when I connect external monitors to my computer nothing happens.

`xrandr -q`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 3840 x 2160, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 3840 x 2160
default connected 3840x2160+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3840x2160     88.00*
```

Up until yesterday it would list DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-4.

How can I fix this?

Some context:

- I don't know that I've updated anything
- The laptop has an nvidia graphics card with version 535 drivers
- The laptop is in balanced energy mode